# reversing output of values in array

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="test"><h2>test</h2></div>

var obj = [
 {num:"1", txt:"text of 1"},
 {num:"2", txt:"text of 2"},
 {num:"3", txt:"text of 3"},
 {num:"4", txt:"text of 4"},
 {num:"5", txt:"text of 5"},
];
$.each(obj, function (i, value) {
  $('#test h2').after(obj[i].txt + "<br>");
});
```

And the output is always reversed:

```
text of 5
text of 4
text of 3
text of 2
text of 1
```

I tried to do this, but it didn't work - the result is the same:

```
$($(obj).get().reverse()).each(function (i, value) {
  $('#test h2').after(obj[i].txt + "<br>");
});
```

What I want is to make the output in the logic order, from 1 to 5 instead of from 5 to 1, how may I achieve this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `.after()` insert element after the specified element i.e. `h2` thus you are getting the result.

You were very close, just need to `reverse()` `obj` object

```
$.each(obj.reverse(), function(i, value) {
    $('#test h2').after(obj[i].txt + "<br>");
});
```

```js
var obj = [{
  num: "1",
  txt: "text of 1"
}, {
  num: "2",
  txt: "text of 2"
}, {
  num: "3",
  txt: "text of 3"
}, {
  num: "4",
  txt: "text of 4"
}, {
  num: "5",
  txt: "text of 5"
}, ];
$.each(obj.reverse(), function(i, value) {
  $('#test h2').after(obj[i].txt + "<br>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <h2>test</h2>
</div>
```

---

You can just use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) element to parent `test` div.

```
$('#test').append(obj[i].txt + "<br>");
```

```js
var obj = [{
  num: "1",
  txt: "text of 1"
}, {
  num: "2",
  txt: "text of 2"
}, {
  num: "3",
  txt: "text of 3"
}, {
  num: "4",
  txt: "text of 4"
}, {
  num: "5",
  txt: "text of 5"
}, ];
$.each(obj, function(i, value) {
  $('#test').append(obj[i].txt + "<br>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <h2>test</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I knew about append, but didn't think it will work this way, thanks. However, why does `after` behave like this and, if I want to use the `after` instead of `append`, how may I reverse this order?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `after`, everytime you value is appending immediately after `h2`. So use append instead.

```js
var obj = [
 {num:"1", txt:"text of 1"},
 {num:"2", txt:"text of 2"},
 {num:"3", txt:"text of 3"},
 {num:"4", txt:"text of 4"},
 {num:"5", txt:"text of 5"},
];
$.each(obj, function (i, value) {
  $('#test').append(obj[i].txt + "<br>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"><h2>test</h2></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for revealing me the reason for why the `after` is reversing the order.

Answer (score 0):

Its really help you

```
$($(obj).get().sort()).each(function (i, value) {
  $('#test h2').after(obj[i].txt + "<br>");
});
```